# Form not loaded while calling jquery validator

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, publish-subscribe

I have a registration form in jsp and i am validating the form in js file using jquery as shown in below code. When i call form() method of jquery validate, it says this.formValidation 'undefined' because my form is not loaded. i have tried setTimeout and delay methods but my problem did not solve. Please help me, my code:

```
UserRegistration.prototype.formValidation = function(){
    var me = this;
    this.formValidation = $('#user_form').validate({
        rules : $.extend({}, rules)
    });
    if (this.formValidation !== 'undefined') {
        this.formValidation.form();
    }
    else {
        setTimeout(this.formValidation.form(), 50);
    }
};
```

In else condition the error occurs.

In Jsp page i am loading my js file using headjs like:

```
head.load("scripts/userregistration.js");
```

Below that i have my form:

```
<form id="user_form">
</form>
```

How can i load my form by the time i call this.formValidation.form();

Comment: Did you try not calling the function, but referencing it `setTimeout(this.formValidation.form, 50);`

Comment: Still if 'this.formValidation' is undefined, error remains same i think.But i didnt try. Can you please tell the reason to refer instead of calling form().

Comment: Why the timer?  The `.validate()` method is only used for *initializing* the validation plugin on your form, it is **not** for triggering validation.

Comment: Initially i have used only 'this.formValidation.form()' .As i got undefuned error for 'this.formValidation' o am tryinh to delay calling form() before loading formValidation.

Comment: You need to start from scratch and solve the original problem... there is no need for a timer here.

Comment: Quote: *"When i call `form()` method of jquery, it says this.formValidation 'undefined'"* ~ There is no `form()` method in jQuery.  Have you included the jQuery Validate plugin??

Comment: Yes i have included Sparky